# Text in minipage produces underfull hboxes

Tags: minipage, hyphenation

After solving all my LaTeX related problems that occured during the writing of my bachelors thesis, I now had to sign up for this problem that I really couldnt solve so far, I hope you guys can help me with this.

Whenever I put longer text in a minipage, I get lots of underfull hboxes. That is while I use NO problematic line breaks like `\\` or `\newlines` or whatsoever. It is just plain text. After 3-4 hours I was able to deduce, that lengthy words (I write in german) are the problem. See for yourself in the following mwe. The first minipage gets compiled flawlessly, no underfull hboxes. The second one gives 3 badbox warnings (underfull hbox) with differing badness. The third one gives 9 (!) underfull hbox warnings, so the attempt to ease hyphenation issues made it worse.

Does anyone have an idea? I am using Texmaker 5.0.3 and MiKTeX Console 2.9.7076.

Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{180pt}
This is a random example text that I wrote myself, it is only a manual replacement for blindtext. This is a random example text that I wrote myself, it is only a manual replacement for blindtext. This is a random example text that I wrote myself, it is only a manual replacement for blindtext. This is a random example text that I wrote myself, it is only a manual replacement for blindtext. 
\end{minipage}%

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{minipage}{180pt}
This text produces underfull hboxes with long german Dokumentenzulassungsstellenbeamter words. This text produces underfull hboxes with long german Dokumentenzulassungsstellenbeamter words. This text produces underfull hboxes with long german Dokumentenzulassungsstellenbeamter words. This text produces underfull hboxes with long german Dokumentenzulassungsstellenbeamter words. 
\end{minipage}%

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{minipage}{180pt}
This text produces underfull hboxes with long german Dokumenten\-zulassungs\-stellen\-beamter. This text produces underfull hboxes with long german Dokumenten\-zulassungs\-stellen\-beamter. This text produces underfull hboxes with long german Dokumenten\-zulassungs\-stellen\-beamter. This text produces underfull hboxes with long german Dokumenten\-zulassungs\-stellen\-beamter. 
\end{minipage}%

\end{document}
```

Using \blindtext works, by the way (no underfull hboxes).

Comment: Typesetting long words in narrow pages is tricky, and you will probably not escape from a bit of manual tweaking. However loading `microtype` has a good chance of improving things...

Comment: this indeed reduced the badbox warnings to three warnings for the 2nd minipage and one for the 3rd. thanks!

Comment: Ending the text with With a `\emergencystretch1em` you will host two more warnings in the second minipage.

Comment: As I said, you will probably need some manual tweaking in the longer words. But yes, `microtype` is magic :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, load `microtype`. It will work magic in your document.

Second, typesetting long words in narrow pages is tricky. TeX tries its best to get the best line breaking for your paragraph, but it will struggle when there's not many options. A really long word in a narrow column will reduce the number of inter word spaces TeX can stretch or shrink, so more stretching/shrinking is applied to fewer spaces, and then badness grows quickly. In this situation you will hardly escape from a bit of manual tweaking in your Überlangedeutschewörter ;-)

One option is rewriting some bits of the sentence to try to have a better line breaking option. Another option is to play with `\hfuzz`, `\emergencystretch`, `\tolerance`, and so on to have TeX stop complaining. Another option is to simply ignore. If the text is not visually horrible (badness usually less than 1000 or 2000) then the warning is just TeX being picky. Yet another option, if you have control on that, is to change slightly the width of the box you're typesetting in. Here I changed the width of the last two boxes by `2pt` (barely noticeable) and all the remaining warnings disappeared.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{180pt}
This is a random example text that I wrote myself, it is only a manual replacement for blindtext. This is a random example text that I wrote myself, it is only a manual replacement for blindtext. This is a random example text that I wrote myself, it is only a manual replacement for blindtext. This is a random example text that I wrote myself, it is only a manual replacement for blindtext. 
\end{minipage}%

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{minipage}{182pt}
This text produces underfull hboxes with long german Dokumentenzulassungsstellenbeamter words. This text produces underfull hboxes with long german Dokumentenzulassungsstellenbeamter words. This text produces underfull hboxes with long german Dokumentenzulassungsstellenbeamter words. This text produces underfull hboxes with long german Dokumentenzulassungsstellenbeamter words. 
\end{minipage}%

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{minipage}{178pt}
This text produces underfull hboxes with long german Dokumenten\-zulassungs\-stellen\-beamter. This text produces underfull hboxes with long german Dokumenten\-zulassungs\-stellen\-beamter. This text produces underfull hboxes with long german Dokumenten\-zulassungs\-stellen\-beamter. This text produces underfull hboxes with long german Dokumenten\-zulassungs\-stellen\-beamter. 
\end{minipage}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will experiment with that and rewrite some stuff in worst case. You helped!

Answer (score 1):

Typesetting in narrow columns makes things tricky, microtype hels a bit here but you could just allow badness up to (say) 3000 to go without comment (1000 is the default value)

this runs with no warning

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}
\hbadness=3000

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{180pt}
  This is a random example text that I wrote myself, it is only a
  manual replacement for blindtext. This is a random example text that
  I wrote myself, it is only a manual replacement for blindtext. This
  is a random example text that I wrote myself, it is only a manual
  replacement for blindtext. This is a random example text that I
  wrote myself, it is only a manual replacement for blindtext.
\end{minipage}%

\vspace{1cm}


\begin{minipage}{180pt}
  This text produces underfull hboxes with long german
  Dokumentenzulassungsstellenbeamter words. This text produces
  underfull hboxes with long german Dokumentenzulassungsstellenbeamter
  words. This text produces underfull hboxes with long german
  Dokumentenzulassungsstellenbeamter words. This text produces
  underfull hboxes with long german Dokumentenzulassungsstellenbeamter
  words.
\end{minipage}%

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{minipage}{180pt}
  This text produces underfull hboxes with long german
  Dokumenten\-zulassungs\-stellen\-beamter. This text produces
  underfull hboxes with long german
  Dokumenten\-zulassungs\-stellen\-beamter. This text produces
  underfull hboxes with long german
  Dokumenten\-zulassungs\-stellen\-beamter. This text produces
  underfull hboxes with long german
  Dokumenten\-zulassungs\-stellen\-beamter.
\end{minipage}%

\end{document}
```

But note hbadness only affects the warning level it doesn't actually change the typesetting. 3000 though allows these cases to go through while still catching a really gross line that just has two small words and a massive stretched space in the middle.

The setting here is particularly difficult as you are using German hyphenation rules but half the words are English and also the first line is necessarily underfull. By choosing where to break the lines in a long paragraph TeX has a lot of flexibility to avoid needing to over-stretch the space , but there is essentially no flexibility in the first line. It ends in the fake word hboxes which defeats any hyphenation rule and the whole word does not fit on the line so the only possible break on line 1s at hbo-/xes even with microtype that line overstretches the space to give

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 1394) in paragraph at lines 25--32
```

that amount of stretching is the only possibility (unless you re-write the text) so the only possibilities are to increase the amount of allowed stretch even more so that amount is calculated as a lower badness, or as I suggest here accept a higher level of badness, neither changes the actual output.

Comment: Thank you! My example text probably was suboptimal, I agree. I was hesitant to post the original german text which is causing me trouble, though. However, I now better understand the issue. You helped a newbie. ;)